# Given two C# projects on the same base directory, how to use different packages.config for each

Tags: nuget

I have two projects (*.csproj) on the same directory (I am porting and this seems like a good workflow) however the problem is that I can only have 1 `packages.config` on the folder. 
I have tested having the project on a different folder and linking the files I need, however, when there are hierarchies of folders, this is a bit convoluted 
Is there a way to use a file named differently? or a better way to deal with this configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can name the packages.config file after each project and Visual Studio will use a separate one for each project even if they are in the same directory.

So if you have Foo and Bar projects then you can rename the existing packages.config files to:

- packages.Foo.config
- packages.Bar.config

If you have a space in your project name then that will need to be replaced with an underscore. So a project called "Foo Bar" would need a packages.config file of:

- packages.Foo_Bar.config

Comment: Could you point out the relevant NuGet documentation?
What if the project name contains characters such as brackets or parentheses?

Comment: @BladeWise - The only place I have seen this documented is in a [release note](https://docs.nuget.org/release-notes/nuget-2.8) which does not mention spaces. The answer above is based on reading the NuGet source code. Only spaces are treated differently, being replaced with underscore, all other characters in the project name are not changed.